# Notifying clients from (boxed) Syncfusion Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-2.0, syncfusion

I'm trying to integrate the schedule component from Syncfusion. The component has a URL adaptor to connect to the controller; GetData() and Batch() for Crud Operations. Batch has a payload indicating what actions to perform. At the end, the Batch method would requery the database and send data identical to GetData() back.
Unfortunately, there is no built-in method to notify clients of anything going wrong - whether there is an exception, server-side validation kicks in or similar.
What I'd like to do is to add a placeholder outside the compentent to receive and display server messages (be it a notification popup, a  or whatever.
Since I can't influence the Ajax call itself, I was wondering if I had to get started with SignalR (still in beta for .Net Core 2 as far as I know), or if I may have missed something more obvious? I have read a lot about push notifications etc - but these are not quite what I'm after, it'd be slightly over the top I think.

To summarise, let's say I have

```
<div id="messages"></div>
<div id="component">HereGoesTheScheduleWhichICantDoMuchWith</div>
```

Now in the Batch() method, it would be great to call a SendMessage("Sorry,you can't do this") -  the text of which would ideally then appear in the messages-div. 
How would you go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this, using SignalR (currently 1.0.0-alpha2-final) and for a nice view on the Client, PNotify.
Presently, it only works if the client is authenticated, if it needs to work anonymously you'd need to figure out a way to track SignalR's connection id.

1. On the page with the Syncfusion Schedule component, I connect to SignalR.

   let connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/signalr", { transport: signalR.TransportType.ServerSentEvents });

   connection.on("Notify",
       (title, message) => {
           new PNotify({
               title: title,
               text: message
           });
       });
   connection.start();
2. The Hub (SignalRHub : Hub) creates a notification group for the user connecting:

   public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
   {
       Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
       return base.OnConnectedAsync();
   }
3. The associated controller gets `IHubContext<SignalRHub> signalRHub` injected.
4. Now in the Batch-Method for the Syncfusion component, which returns Json and can't itself carry messages or notifications, you can notify the user:

   _signalRHub.Clients.Group(User.Identity.Name).InvokeAsync("Notify", "A title", "A message");

In my particular case, I'm sending over an object to control layout, animation and popup duration for PNotify (e.g. longer for an exception to allow copy/paste etc) - as you please. Returning an object could be done using:

```
_signalRHub.Clients.Group(User.Identity.Name).InvokeAsync("Notify", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { title = "Some Title", message = "notification", type = "notice"}););
```

Obviously, `connection.on("Notify"`... needs to be changed accordingly.

I hope this is clear enough and might help someone else.